# understanding azure heartbeat queries

Tags: azure-log-analytics

I have a queries(Distribution by Agent Category)

```
Heartbeat | summarize AggregatedValue = count() by Category
```

which return some response like : Direct Agent  4,222

I have four Vms and the number returned is not matching to number of Vms. My understanding is that we install one log agent per linux Vm and if that's true then how come I get something like 4222? Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Category property defines whether the logs are directly obtained from LA agent or SCOM Agent or SCOM Management Server. To understand each of the properties in Heartbeat table, kindly refer [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/reference/tables/heartbeat).

Heartbeat records are logged once per minute for each virtual machine.You can verify by rounding values to an integer within given bin size for each of the virtual machine. Here is a sample kusto query for reference.

```
Heartbeat
| where TimeGenerated >= ago(2h) and ResourceType == "virtualMachines"
| summarize count() by Computer , Category , bin(TimeGenerated, 1h)
```

Kindly note if there is discrepancy in the count of the heartbeats sent in a hour, then it may be due to intermittent issues or the virtual machine is not reachable at specific time in the interval.

Comment: Kindly read the question , the question is why there is a mis match in response, can you highlight in the documentation where it explains this that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the OS, use this query:

Heartbeat
| where TimeGenerated > ago(12h)
| summarize dcount(Computer) by OSType,OSName,OSMajorVersion, OSMinorVersion