# Kusto Query for Azure VM heartbeat sorted by Tags

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, azure-log-analytics

I need to call heartbeats from very specific machines by tags. The tags are so that multiple machines that function as a single service can have the same tag and availability can be checked for the service as a whole. I cannot for the life of me get anything to work. or find any answers.

Comment: You can refer to [Best way to alert on Heart Beat Alert in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/157178/best-way-to-alert-on-heart-beat-alert-in-azure.html), [understanding azure heartbeat queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65098104/understanding-azure-heartbeat-queries) and [How to implement Azure Monitoring Alert VM Heartbeat with Log Workspace using Terraform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69646321/how-to-implement-azure-monitoring-alert-vm-heartbeat-with-log-workspace-using-te)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.